# Failed to install 'corodova-plugin-googleplus'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-plus

I want to try out my app for the first time on iOS, but I got some troubles, if I do "cordova platform add ios" every plugin is installing fine, but then it says : Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-googleplus': undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading plugin version to 7.0.1. it should fix your problem. this version doesn't use POD dependencies.